# Pass Value in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created two pages, called ViewController and SecViewController. In ViewController, which is the first page, with one button and one label. And I set segue on a button to SecViewController, which is the second page.

I am trying to pass the segue identifier to page 2, but this is not success. I test the value passing in page1, the console display

> 2013-07-05 10:33:54.554 Testing2[1314:c07] 1, (null)

Here is my code:
Anyone can identify which code I typing wrong?

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class SecViewController;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;

@property (strong, nonatomic) SecViewController *view2;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize label, button, view2;

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"1"]){
        view2.received  = [segue identifier];
        NSLog(@"%@, %@", [segue identifier], view2.received);
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [label setText:@"Game Start!"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

SecViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) id received;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@end
```

SecViewController.m

```
#import "SecViewController.h"

@implementation SecViewController

@synthesize label;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to create a property for the second view controller.  You can get it in the prepareForSegue and access the received variable from the second view controller.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"1"]){
        SecViewController *vc  = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.received = [segue identifier];
        NSLog(@"%@, %@", [segue identifier], vc.received);
    }
}
```

if you nslog in the the secondviewcontroller for the value of the received what do you get?

```
#import "SecViewController.h"

@implementation SecViewController

@synthesize label;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"Received %@",self.received);
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Any reason your passing the value to an id received ? You are just trying to pass a string "1" ?  Maybe set received to NSString   Also what do u mean it's not passing correctly?

Comment: I mean why your code just put the declaration in prepareForSegue, then the thing I want to do is work. But why I declare the property in first view controller, the thing is not work?

Comment: You don't have to declare secondviewcontroller.  You can only get the pointer to the actual secondviewcontroller from the [segue desitnationViewController] otherwise you are only declaring the property and not initializing which means it is pointing to null it is not pointing to your second view controller  I hope that make sense.

Comment: Got that, because I find some books is using my method. LOL. May I have the other question, how can you learn the iOS development efficient? Books? Or other ways?

Comment: I really enjoy the Stanford CS193P class. I am going through it again myself.  It's free and the teacher is the best i've seen.  Check it out You can watch it with iTunes https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/coding-together-developing/id593208016  also join piazza.com where people discuss it.  Just make sure its winter 2013 it's the latest one.  He is teaching iOS 6

Comment: Thx! Would u mind to leave the skype id so that we can have a further discussion. :-)

Comment: Sure.  I don't use skype but you can email me.  My email is yanz[at]devicefuldevelopers.com  Have a good evening!

Comment: Have you received my email?